# IBM BPM mapping list from WebService

Tags: web-services, process, business-process-management

I'm using BPM 7.5.1 and I'm having problem with mapping result from webservice into the local BPM variable. Webservice returns me a list of objects. To be exact I have list of "clients" and each client has some basic info (id, reg. number etc.) All data types seem to be generated properly and webservice returns correct soap data but BPM is unable to map it into variable.

I'm still getting this error:

```
CWLLG0391E: An update operation failed.
    com.lombardisoftware.core.TeamWorksRuntimeException: Property ClientId in class ClientsListResponse is not declared. It must be declared to be used.
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

```
Property ClientId in class ClientsListResponse is not declared.
```

As stated in the error statement, your ClientId in the ClientsListResponse has not been declared. You can try with following:

```
tw.local.ClientsListResponse = new tw.object.listOf.ClientsListResponse;
tw.local.ClientsListResponse[0] = new tw.local.ClientListResponse;
tw.local.ClientsListResponse[0].ClientID = "xxx";
```

Hope it works :)

Answer (score 0):

The WSDL not have the Property ClientId. Could be some different character.

on the other hand, to instantiate an object must be:

tw.object.listOf.ClientsListResponse = new tw.local.ClientsListResponse();

not like this

tw.local.ClientsListResponse = new tw.object.listOf.ClientsListResponse;